# How to Load many images in Recycle View without Problem in android

Tags: android

im using Glide library to load my images from storage to imageView using RecyclerView

all thing good

but when number of images be alot app crashed or should be wait so much to activity load completely
this is my code

```
    public static File DIR_IMG = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyHairSamples");

    private void readExistingImages(){
    File[] images;
    try {
        images= DIR_IMG.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (images[i].isFile() && images[i].length() > 50L) {
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images[i].getAbsolutePath());
                addImage(b, "5", images[i].getName());
            }
            else{
                images[i].delete();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and i using this method in onCreate method

and this is my Adapter Code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(arrayList.get(i).getImageTitle());
    viewHolder.thumbnail.setLabelFor(i);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(arrayList.get(i).getImage())
            .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the images resolution is big, loading will be slow and even your application will crash.

So you can resize your image set like this

```
  Glide.with(context)
        .load(arrayList.get(i).getImage())
        .apply(new RequestOptions().override(400, 400))
        .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
```

**EDIT**

```
  RequestOptions reqOpt = RequestOptions
                        .fitCenterTransform()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .override(300,300)
```

Comment: tnx but its not about resolution .. its about number of images

Comment: You can try caching your images after they are loaded for the first time. `Glide` offers you this. Take a look at edited answer.

Comment: Also you can just compress the Bitmap before adding it to your List

Answer (score 1):

Load images inside the uithread, it is not interrupt the main thread.

Use below code.

```
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Glide.with(context)
        .load(arrayList.get(i).getImage())
        .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is easy to implement, you can see my code i just load image into UiThread

Comment: In your code if multiple image load into main thread then may be app is stuck, that's why i recommend you load image into uithread.

Comment: i use it but it still stuck! how can i change my readExistingImages() method to load images from storage better ?